# Python multithread does not work with OpenGL

Tags: python, multithreading, opengl

I have a basic OpenGL square drawing code that I want to put another thread using Python. This is the normal code which is working well,

```
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

class Drawer:
    def drawQuad(self, x,y,width):
        halfW=width/2
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        glVertex3f(x-halfW, y-halfW, 0)
        glVertex3f(x-halfW, y+halfW, 0)
        glVertex3f(x+halfW, y+halfW, 0)
        glVertex3f(x+halfW, y-halfW, 0)
        glEnd()

    def display(self):
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glLoadIdentity()
        glColor3f(0, 0, 1)
        self.drawQuad(0.0,0.0,0.6)
        glutSwapBuffers( )

class Visualizer:
    drawer = Drawer()
    def __init__(self):
        glutInit(sys.argv)
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB)
        glutInitWindowSize(250, 250)
        glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100)
        glutCreateWindow(sys.argv[0])
        glutDisplayFunc( self.drawer.display )
        glClearColor ( 0, 0, 0, 0 )
        glShadeModel( GL_SMOOTH )
        glutMainLoop()

visualizer = Visualizer()
```

This works on my machine flawlessly. Now, I want to put this on a thread. I did the following,

```
class Thread(threading.Thread):
    visualizer = None
    def run(self):
        self.visualizer = Visualizer()  

thread = Thread()
thread.start()
```

When I run the thread, instead of visualizer itself, it does not work. The OpenGL window does not appear. I cannot see what the problem is.

I tried the `threading` with some other examples, they seemed working well. I am confused a bit. What is the problem with my `threading` approach for OpenGL?

Comment: @ratchetfreak So, how do I make a window in OpenGL that takes some inputs while it is running using Python?

Comment: I think what ratchet freak meant to say is that ***GLUT*** is not meant for threads. You can easily use OpenGL in a multi-threaded environment if your framework allows you to set the *current* OpenGL context. The context can only be active in a single thread at a time. Theoretically, `glutSetWindow (...)` will probably set the current render context, though the API documentation does not describe it as doing such. As for taking input from a window in a single-threaded application, you can use a message pump / event queue the way it's been done for 40+ years ;)

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman can you demonstrate it with a small part of code please?